# Indicator Random Variables- choosing a suitable one

Tags: probability-theory

Consider the case where cards are chosen one at a time without replacement from a deck of cards, until a stopping condition is met. 
1. The stopping condition is a heart or diamond, and Let X denote the number of cards chosen. What is the expectation of X?

I am having trouble choosing a suitable indicator random variable to proceed, can someone kindly help? Also can somebody please tell me some good resources where I can apply such concepts?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In step $n$, the probability of STOP is:
$$P_n(\text{stop})=\frac{26}{52-n+1}$$
Now you may could solve it.